# How to ssh over USB, without using tcprelay.py?

Tags: ssh, usb, forward

Edit: I would like to ssh onto a device, say iPhone/android (with root access) over USB. I can make use of [tcprelay.py](https://github.com/rcg4u/iphonessh/blob/master/python-client/tcprelay.py) to forward ssh port on the device to the USB and then ssh to the device over USB.

tcprelay is a very useful tool but the problem is that it comes with a GNU GPL License and I would like to go for a non GPL solution to achieve the same. Would be great if anyone could suggest such an alternative.

Comment: Can you include more details and information about what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `mobiledevice` here : https://github.com/imkira/mobiledevice

use the `tunnel` option

Comment: This is Mac-only solution